# Lottery ticket generator

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a lottery ticket generator. Lottery tickets in Norway can have 10 rows that you bet on. They contain each 7 numbers. The numbers you can choose from is 1-34. In total i can choose 70 numbers within this range of numbers, but i want every number to be picked two times(68) and two can be picked three times(total of 70 numbers). My program will only give me nine rows of numbers and i can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
import random as r
# picks random number


def pickNumber():
    number = r.randint(1, 34)
    return number
# checks if number is in the list


def checkList(lst, number):
    if not number in lst:
        return True
    return False
# checks the amount a number has occured


def checkNumber(lst, number):
    my_set = None
    if lst[number - 1] == 1:
        return False
    else:
        lst[number - 1] += 1
        my_set = set(lst)
        if len(my_set) == 1:
            for i in range(len(lst)):
                lst[i] = 0
        return True
# Run program


def main():
    occured = []
    for i in range(34):
        occured.append(0)
    ticket = []
    counter = 1
    while True:
        row = []
        while True:
            number = pickNumber()
            if checkList(row, number):
                if checkNumber(occured, number):
                    row.append(number)
            if len(row) >= 7:
                break
        ticket.append(row)
        counter += 1
        if counter == 10:
            break
    for i in range(len(ticket)):
        print(ticket[i])

main()
```

Comment: Start with `counter = 0`. You check for `10` before processing the tenth row.

Comment: Wow, i must be blind. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

(moving comment to answer)

Start with `counter = 0`. You check for 10 before processing the tenth row.